# How to Modify Portions of a Template

Tags: templates

I'm writing a research paper for internal consumption at work; the template that I like has symbols in the corners of each page that I'm unfamiliar with, and would prefer weren't there. How can I modify the template to no longer include those symbols?

[image]

[PNAS Journal Template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/pnas)

Comment: They're crop marks for the printer. None of your business :o)

Comment: The crop marks are generated by calling the package `crop` in the `pnastwo` class file (pnastwo.cls). Commenting line 100 `\RequirePackage[cam,center]{crop}`, line 103 `\renewcommand*\CROP@horigin{-.5truein}` and line 104 `\renewcommand*\CROP@vorigin{-.5truein}` will remove the crop marks. Save the class file with a new name e.g. pnastwonew. Then replace `\documentclass{pnastwo}` in the tex file with `\documentclass{pnastwonew}`. The next problem you will have to deal with is the footer which has the journal name, volume number and issue number. This will also require mods to the class file.

Comment: The template is for submissions to PNAS only. Using it for other publications is not recommended. I recommend to use a minimal template for [scientific reports](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports).

Comment: @Ross You're a genius! :)

Comment: @Johannes_B I realize I'm misusing the template, but the learning curve for LaTeX is too steep for my time frame...I just want to start with a working template and come up to speed through modifying it.

Comment: Reading [basic introductory material](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html) takes you two days, max. Using a jounal templates fom the stat introduces you to bad habits. The template in question uses commands that ae deprecated fo two decades, commands that aren't even eal LaTeX (but TeX), equation envioments that nobody should use anymore and more serious: A syntax that will deeply confuse you when writing a normal research paper or want to submit to another journal. <- My two cents.

Comment: @Johannes_B Those are all good points...I appreciate the help.  I've been wanting to learn LaTeX for quite a while, I just saw this as an opportunity to get my feet wet, though to be completely honest a Word doc would probably meet my needs just fine.  Thanks for the reading material, I'll look it over. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Ross Would you like to convert you comment into an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pnastwo` class file makes crop marks to indicate where the page will be trimmed to produce the finished page size.

The crop marks are produced by three lines in the class file:

1. Line 100 is `\RequirePackage[cam,center]{crop}`, which loads the `crop` package
2. Line 103 is `\renewcommand*\CROP@horigin{-.5truein}`, which redefines the horizontal origin for setting the crop marks
3. Line 104 is `\renewcommand*\CROP@vorigin{-.5truein}`, which redefines the vertical origin.

To eliminate the crop marks, comment these three lines. The steps are:

1. Create a copy of `pnastwo.cls`. Let's call it `jackstemplate.cls`.
2. Go to lines 100, 103 and 104. Put a `%` at the beginning of each line so they won't be executed.
3. Although it is not part of OP's request, the footer includes a reference to PNAS. Remove it by replacing at line 344: `\theurl\hfill\footlinefont PNAS\hskip6pt \vrule depth 2pt\hskip6pt` with:`\theurl\hfill\footlinefont \hskip6pt  \vrule depth 2pt\hskip6pt`
4. Save the new class file.

The `PNAStwo` files linked by the OP on Overleaf includes a starter file, `PNASTMPL.tex`. To use the new class file, change line 36 from `\documentclass{pnastwo}` to `\documentclass{jackstemplate]`.  Editing that starter file to make a simple MWE gives:

```
\documentclass{jackstemplate}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\contributor{Contributor}
\url{myurl}
\copyrightyear{2018}
\issuedate{Issue Date}
\volume{Volume}
\issuenumber{Issue Number}
\title{Title of the publication}
\author{John Smith\affil{1}{Affiliation 1},
James Smith\affil{2}{Affiliation 2}
\and
Jane Smith\affil{1}{}}    
\contributor{The Contributor}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle 
\end{document}
```

[image]